# Opengl/Glut keyboard input trouble

Tags: opengl, glut, opengl-compat

i have an assignment to draw a pyramid onto the screen and then rotate after i press the 'k' key in my keyboard.
Everything works ok, except the rotation part as the program doesn't seem to be noting me pressing the key. The code goes as follows:

```c
void changeSize(int w, int h) {

    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    float ratio = w * 1.0 / h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Set perspective
    gluPerspective(45.0f ,ratio, 1.0f ,1000.0f);

    // return to the model view matrix mode
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void renderScene(void) {

    // clear buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set the camera
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(5.0,5.0,5.0,
              0.0,0.0,0.0,
              0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);

    // put the geometric transformations here

    // put drawing instructions here

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f);

        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glEnd();

    //triangulos da base
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(255.0f,255.0f,255.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
    glEnd();

    //triangulos das faces

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glEnd();

    // End of frame
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// write function to process keyboard events

void rotate (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'k') 
        glRotatef(45,1.0,1.0,0.0);

        glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // init GLUT and the window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200,1200);
    glutCreateWindow("CG@DI-UM");

    // Required callback registry 
        glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
        glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);


    // put here the registration of the keyboard callbacks
        glutKeyboardFunc(rotate);

    //  OpenGL settings
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // enter GLUT's main cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that my program is not noting me pressing the key even tho i am. Im tried only printing the keys that are being pressed, and that works, so i'm really lost here.

Answer (score 0):

`glRotatef` seem to have no effect in `rotate`, because `glLoadIdentity()` is called at the begin of `renderScene`. Actually [`glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) changes the current matrix, but when the scene is rendered (`renderScene`), then [`glLoadIdentity()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) loads the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) to the current matrix.
Anyway it is a bad style to do changes to the current matrix in input event callbacks. Change states and values of variables in the input events and use the variables to set the current model view matrix before the scene is rendered in `renderScene`.

Add a global variable `angle`:

```c
float angle = 0.0f;
```

Change the value of the variable in `renderScene`. e.g:

```c
void rotate (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'k') {
        angle += 45.0f;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
```

And apply the rotation to the current matrix in `renderScene`:

```c
void renderScene(void) {

    // clear buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set the camera
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(5.0,5.0,5.0,
              0.0,0.0,0.0,
              0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);

    // apply rotation
    glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // [...]

}
```